# what is the alternative of VBA macros in Visual studio 2010 office development C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

what is the alternative of VBA macros in Visual studio 2010 office development C# ?

can anybody help me?

Comment: how to write macros using C# in visual studio 210 ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [Office Development in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (was Visual Studio Tools for Office)

Comment: want to know that is there any alternative of macros in visual studio 2010 ?

Comment: Yes, Office Development in Visual Studio allows you to program in C# using the .Net framework and develop Office solutions - follow the link, read, and be enlightened...

Comment: but i dont know how to develope it. I am new to Visual Studio Tools for Office.